# Authlogic: How to block certain IP addresses from signing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Using authlogic in a rails app, I want to prevent users from certain IP addresses to sign up (because of misuse). What would be the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :block_ip_addresses

  protected

  def block_ip_addresses
    head :unauthorized if current_ip_address == "XX.XX.XX.XX"
  end

  def current_ip_address
    request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end
```