# How do you block specific IP adress in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ip

I am in charge of a few live websites made in Ruby on Rails.  I have a few IP adresses that keep attacking these sites and I would like to block their IP adresses.  I know they can get around this wall with a proxy but I do wish to make it harder for them and would love to know where I need to set this up in my ruby on rails app.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: use `request.remote_ip` to check ip address from where the request is coming.

Comment: Yes I know the IP's that I need to block, I am just wondering where I tell the RoR app to block the specific IP.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :block_ip_addresses

  protected

  def block_ip_addresses
    head :unauthorized if current_ip_address == "XX.XX.XX.XX"
  end

  def current_ip_address
    request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10895438/1466095

Comment: Actually, you don't really want this in the controller.  You want to block the IP before it hits the router.  Checkout the rack attack gem, you'll never look back.