# How to handle someone trying to hack my website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I'm going through my 404 logs and I noticed this:

```
302 <158>1 2018-10-20T19:12:36.942085+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/wp-login.php" host=www.makerspro.io request_id=f5929aab-8671-433e-92d0-1e779f997d0a fwd="194.99.106.147" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1923ms status=404 bytes=6042 protocol=http
307 <158>1 2018-10-20T19:12:39.076998+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/blog/wp-login.php" host=www.makerspro.io request_id=ce175bfd-6411-48c2-9328-1b6fccb6ae30 fwd="194.99.106.147" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1629ms status=404 bytes=6042 protocol=http
305 <158>1 2018-10-20T19:12:40.699840+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/wp/wp-login.php" host=www.makerspro.io request_id=17bd87b1-3d8f-48bb-8748-ff9d47250dba fwd="194.99.106.147" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1420ms status=404 bytes=6042 protocol=http
312 <158>1 2018-10-20T19:12:42.599811+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/wordpress/wp-login.php"
```

My website is built on rails, I'm the only developer and it seems like someone is trying to hack my website.
Of course, I don't have wordpress installed or anything like that.

What can I do about this and how can I prevent future attacks?

Comment: How to handle attack with php vectors on your rails application? **Ignore it**.

Comment: Until unless you don't disclose server credentials one can't hack you website, feel free to ask any further help

Comment: Thank you, I obviously don't disclose my credentials, but isn't there a way to blacklist their IP or something?

Comment: @MaayanNaveh see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199495/how-do-you-block-specific-ip-adress-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Also, this gem (the documentation is pretty good) https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Comment: @Ideld thanks, that's perfect! Could you please answer in the main question so I can accept it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are generic attacks that happen constantly, and is done by scripts.

The best course is to make sure you are not vulnerable, then ignore them. If you do not have Wordpress, then you have nothing to worry about regarding requests to /wp-login.php.

If you want to harden your application, make sure you have security measures like described in the RoR documentation (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).